# Can we have full choice prior to Reinhardt cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice, embeddings

Working in $\sf ZF + Reinhardt \ cardinal$, can we have full choice over all stages $V_{\alpha < \kappa}$ where $\kappa$ is the Reinhardt cardinal, i.e., the critical point of the elementary embedding $j : V\to V$? That is, every nonempty family of nonempty sets belonging to those stages has a choice function over it.

Comment: Yes, this is answered by my answer to your previous question. One can have $\text{DC}_{\lambda}$ where $\lambda = \kappa_\omega(j)$ which in particular implies that every set in $V_\lambda$ can be wellordered.

Comment: @Gabe But that argument requires somewhat more than just the existence of Reinhardt cardinals.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Would choice below $\kappa$ work without the assumption of $\kappa$ being a limit of Lowenheim-Skolem cardinals?

Comment: My recollection is that if we start with Reinhardt plus DC, then the Woodin forcing up to $\lambda$ will preserve the Reinhardt and force $V[G]_\lambda\vDash \text{AC}$, but it wasn't clear whether one could remove the DC assumption. This issue might be discussed at the end of my paper "Even ordinals and the Kunen inconsistency."